# How can I use the Google Analytics API to pull GA Account Change History?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I want to be able to pull the Change History report from Google Analytics... any ideas/help would be much appreciated!

*It looks like the AdWords API offers this function, but I need it for the Analytics API

Comment: Can you provide more insight into your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The relevant API for this would be the [management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/), but that does not list a function to get the account history, so you do not have programmatic access to that.

You could probably write a script using a bowser automation framework like [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) that logs into Google Analytics using your own credentials, navigates to the account history, downloads the HTML content of the account summary page and then parses it to extract the desired information, but that would not involve the Analytics API at all (and is nothing that can adequately described in a Stackoverflow answer).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance!